# Dropping mutliple columns with specific text of a dataframe within a list of dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and each dataframe has columns that contains columns names such as "Unnamed 1", "Unnamed 2" etc

I want to drop all columns that contain the name "Unnamed" from each dataframe in the list of dataframes.

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]
df_all2 = []

for df in df_all:
    df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed')))]
    df_all2 = df.append
    df_all = df_all2
```

This works, however, is there a more succinct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way by using regex column `filter` with negative lookahead

```
df_all = [df.filter(regex=r'^(?!Unnamed)') for df in df_all]
```

Comment: perfect thanks.  if I wanted to add in a second string of text to exclude would that be possible as well?

Comment: You can use regex or switch: `r'^(?!Unnamed|foo|bar)'` this will also exclude columns starting with either foo or bar

Answer (score 1):

```
for df in df_all:
    df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed:')], 1, inplace=True)
```